# Prevent Chrome from accessing passwords on the web?

Tags: google-account, browser, chrome-for-android, password

I have my Google Account set on my android phone. But I want to prevent passwords from being saved on my phone and my possibility of people accessing my password list on my Google Account.

Is this possible? If so, how?